# Calories retrieved through Google Fit Api does not match Calories count displayed in Google Fit Official App

Tags: javascript, google-fit

I'm using [google javascript api](https://apis.google.com/js/client.js). For getting calories I'm using next datasources:

- derived:com.google.calories.expended:com.google.android.gms:from_activities
  is for calories burned from activities
- derived:com.google.calories.expended:com.google.android.gms:from_bmr
  is for calories burned according your BMR

I can also do it in one call using datasource - 
derived:com.google.calories.expended:com.google.android.gms:merge_calories_expended

My call looks like this:

```
gapi.client.fitness.users.dataSources.datasets.get({
     userId: 'me',
     dataSourceId: 'derived:com.google.calories.expended:com.google.android.gms:merge_calories_expended',
     datasetId: '1465117200000000000-1465164000000000000'
     }).execute(function (resp) { ......... });
```

But values returned are totally different from those I have in my Google Fit App (android or web).

What I have already done:

- Checked all different datasources (fetched via fitness.users.dataSources.datasets.get) which has 'calories' word - no match with Fit App. Those don't match:

derived:com.google.calories.bmr:com.google.android.gms:from_height&weight - totally empty
derived:com.google.calories.bmr:com.google.android.gms:merged - totally empty
derived:com.google.calories.expended:com.google.android.gms:from_activities - returns, but different from Fit App
derived:com.google.calories.expended:com.google.android.gms:from_bmr - returns, but different from Fit App
derived:com.google.calories.expended:com.google.android.gms:merge_calories_expended - from_activities + from_bmr
derived:com.google.calories.expended:com.google.android.gms:platform_calories_expended - same as merge_calories_expended

- Checked if it's date related, like different timezone etc.
- Checked stackoverflow

nothing helped :(

Answer (score 0):

Probable cause why values for step/distance/active time/calories do not match those of Fit app given in [Google Fit - Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](https://developers.google.com/fit/faq#values_for_stepdistanceactive_timecalories_do_not_match_those_of_fit_app) is that:

> Because of how Google Fit updates are released, it may be possible that the Google Fit app has a more recent version of our data analysis code than Google Play Services, which is released less often.
>
> Our backends, however, always have the most recent version of the data, and everything gets processed there eventually and should match up after a couple of cloud syncs.

Please try, as suggested, to make it possible for apps to process a cloud sync instantly so that everything is in sync, and also by making it so that syncs happen automatically when significant data is entered or changes.

I hope that will work on your end.

Comment: Thank you,  Teyam,  I have already read those FAQ. But in my case even data that is for ex. 5 days old doesn't match with that in Fit App on Android.